# 1980's children's illustrated book where we are given a tour of other planets

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, planets

I am looking for a children's book from most likely the late 80's. I was born in 87 and remember reading the book as a kid. It was an illustrated book where we are given a tour of other planets and their strange alien inhabitants.

I remember the illustrations being colorful, Peter Max (the *Yellow Submarine* movie) like.

Comment: I couldn't find the question I was thinking of but I am sure this is on here somewhere.  Posted the book I was thinking of as answer.

Comment: Could it be the little prince?

Answer (score 5):

Could it be [*National Geographic Picture Atlas of Our Universe*](https://jfelt.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/someone-got-paid-for-this/)? It had a "What if..." section that had drawings and descriptions of what life on other planets might look like.  For example, Mars:

[image: A black creature with four long tall legs to a bulbous body with a small elephant head, trunk and absolutely massive ears and a massive bushy tail that arches over it's head stands on the red sandy landscape of Mars; another creature lays on its back in the background and an egg can be seen further off into the distance]

Answer (score 4):

I think the book maybe [*Alien World: The Complete Illustrated Guide*](http://www.terrantradeauthority.com/other-books/alien-world-the-complete-illustrated-guide/) published 1980 (the link gives a slide show of the contents).

The book gives a tour of different worlds in a documentary sense.  With many illustrations of the inhabitants.

[image: Book cover showing the name in yellow block writing at the top and then two metal panels riveted together with an alien's eye peering through a melted hole in the centre and a long thin tentacle/tongue coming through]

Answer (score 3):

I know the book. It's called *Galactic Aliens*.

[image: Book cover with a black background, the top has chrome lines on it with Aliens written with them and Galactic above it. The main part of the page is a white bordered image of a round green alien flying through space alongside a goblin-like alien following 3 spacecraft]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this answer to explain *why* you believe that this is the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[Dangerous Frontiers](http://ski-ffy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/galactic-encounters-dangerous-frontiers.html)* by Steven Caldwell

> The ships of the Galactic Federation's Survey and Preliminary Study Service ceaselessly range among the alien stars and unexplored planets which lie beyond the distant Perimeter. Contact with the bustling, central worlds of the Federation is difficult and infrequent as they face the dangers of the vast unknown.
>
> But the prosperity and growth of this great association of worlds would be impossible without new sources of supply and new avenues for expansion. Scarcely more than one in every hundred planets explored proves to be of sufficient interest to justify the implementation of a settlement programme.
>
> All the planets described in Dangerous Frontiers have won a place in the Federation at great cost in lives and efforts, and their existence owes much to the courage and determination of the creatures who first struggled for a foot-hold in their lonely and alien landscapes.
>
> Dangerous Frontiers is a study of those worlds as they are today. Some are vital to the network of trade, others have faded in importance and a few are only just emerging from obscurity. Whatever their current status in the Federation, it is to those who struggled alone in the emptiness beyond the frontiers that the honour belongs.

[image: Dangerous Frontiers book cover with the title written at the top in yellow and a purple space background. In the centre is a blue "hole" in space surrounded by a rainbow twirl that moves into all purple; a yellow spaceship resembling a submarine is flying out of the hole with 3 light beams projecting out in front of it]